# Why is the dimensionality of the $SL(N,{\mathbb{R}})$ and $SU(N)$ groups $N^2-1$ but only $N^2$ for $GL(N,{\mathbb{R}})$ and $U(N)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras

As far as I know the only difference between the two special and normal groups is that the $SL(N,{\mathbb{R}})$ and $SU(N)$ generators must be traceless.

I understand that the dimensionality corresponds to the number of linearly independent matrices in the algebra. So how does the tracelessness of the generating matrices affect their linearity?

Comment: From your mixing up of Lie groups and Lie algebras, I guess you come from physics. --- In the Lie group setting, the extra condition is actually that the determinant is $1$. For Lie algebras, indeed the extra condition is that the trace is $0$. Now especially for this it should be clear why the condition lowers our choice of free matrix entries by $1$, no?

Comment: I mean, to write down a general 2 by 2 matrix, we have four choices $\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}$, right? To make it traceless, $\pmatrix{a&b\\c&-a}$ there's only three. Now generalize.